# how to create dynamic routes and helpers in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

i have a task to create mapping of different urls at run time .
In the application i have  a GUI interface which displays list of routes from routes.rb file.
User has the ability to change that url to some different name from the interface
eg. (abc/mno)  --user can change them to --(hello)
so if user type /hello in the browser request is redirected to /abc/mno
i have to store those mapped routes in a database.
how to add a dynamic mapped route to already defined routes(routes.rb)  while creating a new  record in database
how to add routes from the database while loading routes.rb file.
i am not able to figure out how to extend the default router so that it can include routes from the database ..

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete solution for you, but you can start with two approaches:

- Use custom URL constraint: [Dynamic URL -> Controller mapping for routes in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596312/dynamic-url-controller-mapping-for-routes-in-rails)
- Use Rack middleware: [Dynamic Rails routing based on database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518799/dynamic-rails-routing-based-on-database)

Comment: problem of creating a controller that handles all routing is that ..  when user creates a mapping from gui that mapping is not reflected until i restart my server again..different path_helpers are also not available

Comment: @BlueSmith The second link posted by BlueSmith is pretty much dead on.  The example shown is a good starting point,  the changes should be straightforward to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use rack middleware, you can use constraints.  Hopefully, your dynamic routes are scoped to something, like "/abc/*anything-after-here-can-be-dynamic*", as opposed to straight off the root...

So, lets say you wanted dynamic routes based upon User's first name, then you would do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
match '/abc/:route' => "abc#dynamicroute", :contraints => DynamicRouteConstraint.new

#lib/dynamic_route_constraint.rb
class DynamicRouteConstraint < Struct.new
  def matches?(request)
    User.find_by_first_name(request.params[:route]).present?
  end
end

#app/controllers/abc_controller.rb
class AbcController < ApplicationController
  def dynamicroute
    @user = User.find_by_first_name(params[:route])
    #render or redirect, however you wish
  end
end
```

Comment: You don't need to instantiate a new object, you could just call a class method. +1 to your answer because it inspired me to implement my own solution!